# remove outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JavaScript code I have a string that contains something like:

```
var html = "<div class='outer'><div id='inner'>lots more html in here</div></div>";
```

I need to convert this to the string

```
var html = "<div id='inner'>lots more html in here</div>";
```

I'm already using using jQuery in my project, so I can use this to do it if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var html = "<div class='outer'>" 
         + "<div id='inner'>lots more html in here</div></div>";

html = $(html).html();

alert(html);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TTEwm/

Comment: This would also strip the actual `<div id="inner">` tag and return only `lots more html in here`. What you mean is just `$(html).html()` (returns the inner HTML of the outermost element).

Comment: @ajax333221 Nope, `$(html).html()` is correct. Lazz wrote his post before Xander edited to correct his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Why all these needlessly complex answers?

```
//get a reference to the outer div
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('outerDivId');//or $('#outerDivId')[0];
outerDiv.outerHTML = outerDiv.innerHTML;
```

And that's it. Just set the outerHTML to the inner, and the element is no more.

---

Since I had overlooked that you're dealing with an HTML string, it needs to be parsed, first:

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
var outerDiv = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];//will be the outer div
outerDiv.outerHTML = outerDiv.innerHTML;
```

And you're done.

Comment: Either way, what you do then is parse them first (that's what jQuery does, too) but I'll edit my answer

Comment: I wasn't aware that `var outerDiv = document.getElementById('outerDivId'); outerDiv.innerHTML = outerDiv.innerHTML;` is simplier than `$(html).html();`

Comment: @Chad, same-same. jQuery does the same thing (give or take) behind the scenes, this approach (if used well) will perform faster, though. That, and I overlooked that answer (it's very short indeed)

Comment: Why the downvote? I have no problems with them, as long as there is a good reason for them

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm not saying that they *do* anything different, I'm saying that the jquery 14 character one-liner is simpler. Especially when you have to parse the string first, like in your second answer.

Comment: @Chad, I know you didn't say they did different things. My point is: jQuery parses the string, too, using an enclosed div element. The only difference (except for the code you write yourself) is that pure JS will run faster

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Your code is not only more complex, it is [slower](http://jsperf.com/vanilla-vs-jquery-parse). Only in Chrome does your code have a *small* performance bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) -

```
$("#inner").unwrap();
```

Comment: This will return a jQuery object, not a string as he wanted. It is simplier to do `$(html).html();`

Comment: @Chad you are right, why don't you post your answer? you were the 1st who answered correctly

Comment: Because Xander updated his answer to what I had said originally, so i don't want to repost the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

If html string always look like in your example you can use this simple code

```
var html = "<div class='outer'><div class='inner'>lots more html in here</div></div>";
html = html.slice(19,-6)
```

Comment: This solution looks very brittle, it will break if spaces are added

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var html = "<div id='inner'>" + html.split("<div id='inner'>")[1].split("</div>")[0] + "</div>";
```

But you may want to add more protection for variations (in case you have the bad habit of not writing code using the same conventions), e.g `"inner"` or `<DIV>`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anYtL/)